# Object instantiated as "new" from closure cannot directly access properties of returned object

Tags: javascript, closures, memoization

I am trying to create a JavaScript library of UI components that are commonly used by the projects in my group. I have the following code to define the library.

```
var libName = function() {
    var _libName = this;

    _libName.componentName = function () {
        // Some Private Variables

        var _componentName = function (args) {
             // Construct the object...
        };

        _componentName.addObject = function (args) {
            // Add an object...
        };

        _componentName.removeObject = function (args) {
            // Remove an object...
        };

        return _componentName;
    }();

    return _libName;
}();
```

Now, when I use this in a page to create the component I call the following code.

```
var component = new libName.componentName(args);
```

It initializes just fine and creates the base component that I expect. Now I want to add some data to the component, so I call the following function.

```
component.addObject(someObject);
```

But instead of calling the function like I expect it to, it says that the component object does not have a property 'addObject'. I looked into this with the following code.

```
if (libName.componentName.addObject) {
    console.log("libName.componentName.addObject exists");    // Logs
} 

if (component.addObject) {
    console.log("component.addObject exists");                // Doesn't log
}

if (component.constructor.addObject) {
    console.log("component.constructor.addObject exists");    // Logs
}
```

So my question is what exactly is going on here? Why does an object, in this case component, not have access to the properties/functions I expect it to? Does this have something to do with the fact that I am using memoized closures to define the library? How do I make it so that an object initialized from this library has access to these properties/functions?

Comment: there is little point using all these closures and self invoking functions , especially when using prototypal inheritance in javascript. One module per library is enough.Furthermore private variables in your _componentName instances will be shared across all instances, if that's what you want , fine , but they will not be instance variables.

Comment: So we're on the same page:

   `_libName = this;` You want `_libName` to point to `window`?


    `_componentName = function () {}`

...does `_componentName` use `this` in anticipation of being called with `new`, or is it a factory that's going to return an object of a specific type, regardless of whether `new` is called or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the prototype of the function to define instance methods :

```
    _componentName.prototype.addObject = function (args) {
        // Add an object...
    };

    _componentName.prototype.removeObject = function (args) {
        // Remove an object...
    };
```

your script doesnt work because you are calling _componentName properties , that are not passed to instances of _componentName if defined directy on the object. Remember using **new** mean using prototypal inheritance. Javascript doesnt have class based inheritance.